# Search by tag delay?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

Not sure if it's a stackexchange thing, or just because the site is new, but I can't seem to find all the related tags for a tag.

E.g. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2 currently returns 1 result, but I know that there are at least 3 tagged with this on the front page alone.

It might be due to the fact I think people are detagging `teamfortress2` to `team-fortress-2`, I'm not sure.

Sorry if this belongs on meta-meta.

Comment: I was retagging so maybe due to that.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce. I see 8 results.. maybe you're running into caching of lists?